# Modificar archivo.txt y generar Array con Python

Tags: python, array, archivo

tengo un archivo.txt con 400 lineas que tiene la siguiente estructura: (es un js en txt)

```
/* texto1 */ var texto2 = blablabla;
```

Y necesito generar un Array bidimensional con los dos textos, algo así:

```
array [ ["texto1", "texto2"], ["texto1", "texto2"].....]
```

Y asi la 400 lineas, pensé en hacerlo en Python pero soy muy novato en el lenguaje no se como hacerlo...

Haber si me podeis hechar una mano en python o cualquier 
otro lenguaje me vale...

Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Cualquier lenguaje que soporte expresiones regulares te servirá. Basta escribir una expresión regular que "encaje" con el patrón que tienen tus líneas y recorrer cada línea del fichero aplicando ese patrón y recogiendo los resultados en una lista.

La expresión regular sería la siguiente:

```
^\/\*\s+(.+?)\s+\*\/\s+var\s+(.+?)\s.*
```

que básicamente dice "todas las líneas deben comenzar, `^`,  por una barra seguida de un asterisco, `\/\*`, (hay que ponerles delante la barra inversa pues la barra directa y el asterisco son caracteres especiales dentro de una expresión regular), seguida de uno o más espacios, `\s+`, seguidos de un grupo compuesto por cualquier secuencia de caracteres, `(.+?)` (el grupo va entre paréntesis, y `.*` representa cualquier caracter repetido una o más veces, el interrogante final es para evitar que ese grupo se trague todo lo que haya hasta el último espacio, y se detenga en cambio al llegar al primer espacio), seguido de uno o más espacios, `\s+`, seguidos de otro asterisco y otra barra, `\*\/`, seguidos de uno o más espacios `\s+` y la palabra `var`, seguida de uno o más espacios, `\s+`, y de otro grupo de captura que capture todos los caracteres que encuentre hasta el siguiente espacio `(.+?)\s`, seguido ya de cualquier secuencia de caracteres hasta el final de la línea, `.*`.

Puedes ver esta expresión regular en acción [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/4LpxPN/1)

Un programa en python que aplique esta expresión regular a cada línea de un fichero y recolecte los resultados en una lista bidimensional como la que pides sería así:

```
import re

expresion_regular = r"^\/\*\s+(.+?)\s+\*\/\s+var\s+(.+?)\s.*"

resultado = []
with open("fichero.js") as f:
  for linea in f:
     match = re.match(expresion_regular, linea)
     if match:
        resultado.append(list(match.groups()))

print(resultado)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda pero me da el siguiente error:

Comment: **Traceback (most recent call last):**
  **File "c:\Users\usuario\Desktop\projects\prueba\programa.py", line 6, in <module> with open("fichero.js") as f:**


**`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fichero.js`**

Comment: Y el **fichero.js** si que está en la misma ruta.

Comment: Pues el mensaje de error te dice que no está. ¿Estarás ejecutando tu script desde algún IDE que cambie la ruta? ¿Has probado a ejecutarlo directamente desde una terminal?

Comment: Era el IDE (VSCode) que estaba haciendo de las suyas... Muchas Graciaas!